# Accionar Botón mediante bucle

Tags: javascript

Hola amigos tengo un problema, os comento,tengo un código **php** que se genera en *bucle*, dependiendo de la cantidad de elementos que tenga en el `array` pues se generará la misma cantidad de botones con su nombre identificativo personal(Botonmas(1),Botonmas(2)...). Seguidamente contiene una etiqueta `echo` con un bucle en **javascript** con el que intento realizar la acción de un botón mediante un *bucle* para ahorrarme tiempo en cliquear código, la cosa es que no funciona, claro esta... jeje. Yo he usado un *bucle for*, no sé si para estos casos seria mejor usar **recursividad**

Aquí os dejo el código:

```
$ResultadoProductos= mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM $tablaamenities_conexion");


$array_num = count($arrayProductos);

for ($b = 0; $b <$array_num; $b++){



$consultaProducto= mysqli_fetch_array($ResultadoProductos);

$comprobacionProducto=$consultaProducto['id'];

if($arrayProductos[$b]== $comprobacionProducto)
    ($arrayProductos[$b]);
        {
            $arrayProductos[$b];



            $ContarP =$consultaProducto['id'];

            echo'

            <div onclick=" Botonmas('.$ContarP.')"><span id="Boton01" ">+</span></div>

            <script>

            var ID="'.$ContarP.'";



            function  Botonmas(valor){


                if(valor==ID)
                {
                    alert("funciona".ID);

                }





                        }

            </script>
```

PD: Lo que realmente nececesito es que el fragmento que pongo abajo sea automático referente al valor del botón.

```
    if(valor==ID)
                {
                    alert("funciona".ID);

                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo necesitas agregarle una clase al `div` que tiene como atributo `onclick` un class único

De este modo

```php
<?php
$ResultadoProductos= mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM $tablaamenities_conexion");
$array_num = count($arrayProductos);
for ($b = 0; $b < $array_num; $b++) {
$consultaProducto = mysqli_fetch_array($ResultadoProductos);
$comprobacionProducto = $consultaProducto['id'];
if ($arrayProductos[$b] === $comprobacionProducto) {
  if ($arrayProductos[$b]) { // me supongo que esto es un if
    $arrayProductos[$b];
    $ContarP = $consultaProducto['id'];
?>
<div class="boton" onclick="Botonmas(<?php echo $ContarP; ?>)"><span id="Boton<?php echo $ContarP; ?>">+</span></div>
<script>
  var boton = document.querySelectorAll('.boton');
  function  Botonmas(valor) {
    alert('Click en el botón No.' + valor);
  }
  boton.forEach(function(b) {
    // aquí se efectúa el auto-click
    b.click();
  });
</script>
<?php
    } // se cierra el supuesto if
  } // se cierra el anterior if
?>
```

Comment: Hola ante todo muchisimas gracias por tu respuesta pero desgraciadamente no me he explicado correctamente en el apartado principal y poco me ha servido a ver si me podrias echar una mano con la edición.

Comment: me referia al código que he cambiado a ver si te puedes guiar un poco más con lo que he edtiado.

Comment: @DavidRobles ya edite mi respuesta. Por sierto la variable ID descartala ya que pones como valor lo que devuelve `$ContarP`, y al hacerlo de esa forma siempre te devolvera el ultimo valor que devuelva `$ContarP`. Y al poner la sentencia `if (valor === ID)` provocas que solo se le pueda dar click a un solo botón, el cual seria el último

Comment: Eres un maquina Rimuru , muchas gracias :D